# Participle Phrases vs. Reduced Relative Clauses

Tags: present-participles, participle-phrases

I found [this article](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm) about Participle Phrases, It's the first time I hear about them. I always thought they are all reduced relative clauses.

How do they differ from reduced relative clauses?

Consider this example:

> Removing his glasses, the professor shook his head with disappointment.

It seems like the original sentence could be like

> While the professor was removing his glasses, he shook his head with disappointment.

That is obviously more complicated than a simple reduced relative clause. Right? How many types are there? I mean which phrases can be reduced to a particle-phrase?

Comment: They are usually referred to as "adverbial participles",  relative clauses require relative pronouns. "While" is not a relative pronoun, though. "while" is a subordinate conjunction which is usually used to form adverbial clauses.

Comment: Slightly different from "while" which means "concurrently"  is the idea that an action is collateral to or incidental to another action. Clearly the professor would have difficulty shaking his head *while* removing his glasses, or difficulty removing his glasses while shaking his head.

Comment: @cardinal I see you seriously follow English learning. Do you know some good sources accessible online? Some which were most useful for you.

Comment: I used to spend more than 3 hours a day on ell to follow the discusions, and in the chat room. (For instance, StoneyB's answers are awesome. He usually uses accurate jargon which helped me to got familiar with those terms). I started learning English seriously last year. I read the book Cambridge Advanced Grammar In Use completely. In the case of online materials I use dictionaries, grammar girl, and granmar monster and youtube videos. In fact, I am not very selective in my online studies. I often summarize what I learned in the form of tables and notes and review them every now and then.

Comment: @cardinal are you member of WWW .lang-8.com ? People write some entries in a language  and native speakers correct them.

Comment: @Ahmad No. Really? I will check it up. Many thanks.

Comment: @Cardinal I myself noticed its effectiveness recently, check "**Popular Entries**" (More > Popular Entries) to learn from the corrections made for some posted entries, you also can post an entry or correct an entry of a Persian learner.

Comment: @Ahmad I created an account; my nickname is "Paeez".

Answer (score 0):

I guess the difference is in terms of terminology and word order in the sentence. While participles should precede the Subject of the main clause and should be separted by a comma, the reduced relative clause always follows the subject of the main clause or the obect of the main clause.

Hopefully, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When introducing a sentence, a participle phrase functions as a modifier to a main clause ; therefore, it functions adverbially. You can change the same sentence and make the participle modify the noun phrase "the professer" so you can say: "The professor, removing his glasses, ... " in that case, it would be a reduced relative clause.